# Iptables and fail2ban on Yocto Linux

Tags: linux, iptables, yocto, fail2ban

I've installed both iptables and fail2ban on my embedded Yocto-Linux. When fail2ban set the following command:

```
iptables -w -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -j f2b-NoScript
```

I have that error:

```
iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): Couldn't load match `multiport':No such file or directory
```

but the library multiport is present on the following path:

```
/usr/lib/xtables/libxt_multiport.so
```

Any suggestions ?
It is necessary build iptables recipe with other options?

Answer (score 1):

> iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): Couldn't load match `multiport':No such file or directory

This means that you don't have the multiport module for iptables, since it can't load the related .so library (normally it'd be not `/usr/lib/xtables/` but `/usr/lib/iptables/`).
You could invoke `man iptables` to see what you may need for "multiport" module, but...

Since it says "legacy", you may have another primary net-filter sub-system (that `iptables` may just emulate), so you can probably use it directly instead of iptables.

For instance, if it is nftables (`sudo nft -v` answers with version), you can specify this in default section of your `jail.local` (and restart fail2ban):

```
[DEFAULT]
# banaction = nftables-multiport
banaction = nftables[type=multiport]
# banaction_allports = nftables-allports
banaction_allports = nftables[type=allports]
```

However iptables mostly writes `(nf_tables)` instead of `(legacy)` in that case.

So it may be something different. In this case you'd find out which net-filter your system basically uses and choose appropriate [banning action](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/tree/0.11/config/action.d) or write it by yourselves.

If nothing helps or you'd not find the suitable action and no multiport is supported by your system, try to use allports action instead:

```
[DEFAULT]
banaction = iptables-allports
banaction_allports = iptables-allports
```

(just note that in this case it would ban the IP completely, regardless the port configured in jail, so by possible false positives or some test attempts e. g. on http side it could ban your IP for all ports, so it'll be impossible to connect via ssh from that IP to unban manually).

Comment: Thanks a lot Sebres, I understood better how fail2ban works anyway I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I re-compiled the kernel with the following option:

```
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_MULTIPORT=y
```